# Synchronize IMAP mailbox in realtime

Tags: imap

I would like to synchronize IMAP mailbox from one server to another server in realtime. Currently I am using imapsync software which uses (pull method) from one source server to (destination) server to sync the messages.

I have tried mbsync (isync) also but It only supports remote IMAP4 type mailbox not Maildir type.

Can anyone suggest realtime mailbox syncing solution which must be support Maildir remote mailbox type.

Comment: What does the backing store of the IMAP sever have to do with anything?  IMAP hides the backing store, so it doesn't matter whether it's using a database, mbox, Maildir, exchange, .....

Answer (score 1):

As Max said, the issue is not with IMAP. IMAP is merely the protocol for serving messages to clients.

What you want to do is to synchronize the backing store, i.e. the place where the messages are kept. It sounds like you are using Maildir. I don't know Maildir, but since it uses the local filesystem, I would try to sync that between the servers. The simplest solution that I can think of here is to use something like Dropbox for this.

There are some practical reasons why realtime syncing of IMAP messages could be hard though, one of which is that the UID values have to increase with time, so you can not have two servers allocating UIDs without each of them knowing what the last UID was.

I don't think stackoverflow is the right setting for this question, since it does not sound like a development problem. Maybe try https://serverfault.com/